# Distance Calculations for Nearest Mean Classifer

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, nearest-neighbor, euclidean-distance, centroid

Greetins,

How can I calculate how many distance calculations would need to be performed to classify the IRIS dataset using Nearest Mean Classifier.

I know that IRIS dataset has 4 features and every record is classified according to 3 different labels.

According to some textbooks, the calculation can be carried out as follow:

[image]

However, I am lost on these different notations and what does this equation mean. For example, what is s^2 is in the equation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The notation is standard with most machine learning textbooks.  `s` in this case is the sample standard deviation for the training set.  It is quite common to assume that each class has the same standard deviation, which is why every class is assigned the same value.

However you shouldn't be paying attention to that.  The most important point is when the priors are equal.  This is a fair assumption which means that you expect that the distribution of each class in your dataset are roughly equal.  By doing this, the classifier simply boils down to finding the smallest distance from a training sample `x` to each of the other classes represented by their mean vectors.

How you'd compute this is quite simple.  In your training set, you have a set of training examples with each example belonging to a particular class.  For the case of the iris dataset, you have three classes.  You find the mean feature vector for each class, which would be stored as `m1, m2` and `m3` respectively.  After, to classify a new feature vector, simply find the smallest distance from this vector to each of the mean vectors.  Whichever one has the smallest distance is the class you'd assign.

Since you chose MATLAB as the language, allow me to demonstrate with the actual iris dataset.

```
load fisheriris; % Load iris dataset
[~,~,id] = unique(species); % Assign for each example a unique ID
means = zeros(3, 4); % Store the mean vectors for each class
for i = 1 : 3 % Find the mean vectors per class
    means(i,:) = mean(meas(id == i, :), 1); % Find the mean vector for class 1
end

x = meas(10, :); % Choose a random row from the dataset

% Determine which class has the smallest distance and thus figure out the class
[~,c] = min(sum(bsxfun(@minus, x, means).^2, 2));
```

The code is fairly straight forward.  Load in the dataset and since the labels are in a cell array, it's handy to create a new set of labels that are enumerated as 1, 2 and 3 so that it's easy to isolate out the training examples per class and compute their mean vectors.  That's what's happening in the `for` loop.  Once that's done, I choose a random data point from the training set then compute the distance from this point to each of the mean vectors.  We choose the class that gives us the smallest distance.

If you wanted to do this for the entire dataset, you can but that will require some permutation of the dimensions to do so.

```
data = permute(meas, [1 3 2]);
means_p = permute(means, [3 1 2]);
P = sum(bsxfun(@minus, data, means_p).^2, 3);
[~,c] = min(P, [], 2);
```

`data` and `means_p` are the transformed features and mean vectors in a way that is a 3D matrix with a singleton dimension.  The third line of code computes the distances vectorized so that it finally generates a 2D matrix with each row `i` calculating the distance from the training example `i` to each of the mean vectors.  We finally find the class with the smallest distance for each example.

To get a sense of the accuracy, we can simply compute the fraction of the total number of times we classified correctly:

```
>> sum(c == id) / numel(id)

ans =

    0.9267
```

With this simple nearest mean classifier, we have an accuracy of 92.67%... not bad, but you can do better.  Finally, to answer your question, you would need `K * d` distance calculations, with `K` being the number of examples and `d` being the number of classes.  You can clearly see that this is required by examining the logic and code above.